# Accuracy increases using cross-validation and decreases without

Tags: machine-learning, naivebayes

I have a question regarding cross validation: I'm using a Naive Bayes classifier to classify blog posts by author. When I validate my dataset without k-fold cross validation I get an accuracy score of 0.6, but when I do k-fold cross validation, each fold renders a much higher accuracy (greater than 0.8).

For Example:

> (splitting manually): Validation Set Size: 1452,Training Set Size: 13063, Accuracy: 0.6033057851239669

and then

> (with k-fold): Fold 0 -> Training Set Size: 13063, Validation Set Size: 1452 Accuracy: 0.8039702233250621 (all folds are over 0.8)

etc...

Why does this happen?

Comment: please do not cross-post your question on multiple SE sites... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138449/accuracy-increases-using-cross-validation-and-decreases-without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons this could happen:

1. Your "manual" split is not random, and you happen to select more outliers that are hard to predict. How are you doing this split?
2. What is the `k` in k-fold CV? I'm not sure what you mean by Validation Set Size, you have a fold size in k-fold CV. There is no validation set, you run the cross validation using your entire data. Are you sure you're running k-fold cross validation correctly?

Usually, one picks `k = 10` for k-fold cross validation. If you run it correctly using your entire data, you should rely on its results instead of other results.

Comment: k = 10, it was found out that the splitting was not being performed well and the training and testing sets were not being perfectly disjointed. Now the accuracy is consistent. Thank you